# How to use FOREIGN KEY constraints in php for Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create two tables in an existing database using PHP and Mysql, but every time I try I get an error message "Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint". My question was marked as duplicated, but here primary key and foreign key are exactly of the same type (INT), so I am still unable to undestand where is my error.

```
<?php
.... 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Users (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Messaggi (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
messaggio TEXT NOT NULL,
utente INT,
FOREIGN KEY (utente) REFERENCES Users(id),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I think there is an error in my declaration of FOREIGN KEY but I can't find it. Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, in this case I think the problem is that you are overwriting your own $sql variable. The Users table will therefore never be created, resulting in the Foreign Key issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It was a very stupid error, but I wasn't able to see it. You have saved me!

Comment: Glad I could help.